# dynamically setting object name jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have multiple ckEditor instances on one page and I'm trying to send the data via AJAX, if I define the object names manually its all good and I get the data, but I would like to loop through any available ckEditor instances on the page and grab the data for each one.

I guess my question is, how can i set the name of the object to the variable I have defined?

```
        //looping over 2 ckEditor instances
        $(".mapRow[data-fieldType='ckeditor']").each(function () {
            let theEditor = $(this).data('fieldname') + "_Default"; //produces "ckfield1_Default" & "ckfield2_Default"

            console.log(theEditor.getData()); //doesn't work
            console.log(ckfield1_Default.getData()); //does work
            console.log(ckfield2_Default.getData()); //does work
        });
```

Comment: theEditor will be a string, not an object, so thats why i thing `theEditor.getData()` aint working.

Comment: how would I convert the string to be a object name?

Comment: Have you tried console.log(theEditor);, also if you show us how you initialize the editors then maybe we can see the error

Comment: Just select the real ckEditior with a jquery-selector after you got the name in theEditor variable.
Assuming your ckeditor is a div with a name attribute you can use this:
`$("div[name='"+theEditor+"']")`  to select your ckEditor instance

Change "div" as needed.
As @CarstenLøvboAndersen said, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question:

"how can i set the name of the object to the variable I have defined?"

is wrapping the variable in eval()

```
eval(theEditor)
```

whether or not this is best practice, or the best approach is another question.